# Jlabel pathing correctly to an icon

Tags: java, icons, jlabel

I am trying to add an icon to a Jlabel, but I am not getting the icons shown at all.

My Folder Structure is

```
Main Folder > Resources > Icons       > .png files
              src       > .java files
```

In a java file under the src folder I am trying to link to a .png in the Icons folder

[image: example here]

Am I linking to the file incorrectly? Or am I doing something wrong that causes the icons to not be shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your sources and/or classes to a folder where resources is also included. You can also try including the `resources` folder to the project's bin or any folder where compiled classes and sources are located.

If you don't want to move everything then you can get the location where the file is executed, get the location of your resources, then use it to find the file path of an image icon.

```
File file = new File (getClass().getResource("").getPath());  // get the current file path
String path = new String (file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent()); // get the parent of the absolute location of the file.
path = path.replace ("\\", "/"); // replace backward slash with forward slash
label = new JLabel ();
label.setIcon (new ImageIcon (path + "/resources/icons/pawn_black.png"));
```